# Vendor extension superfluous on Chrome and not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, css, vendor-prefix

I've been playing around with the code below, and there are two things i don't quite get. The first one is that Chrome seems to accept the vendorless radius specification. So why should we put in "-webkit" there?

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
border-radius: 30px;
```

I also noticed that the very same commands have no effect in Firefox. The border corner stays sharp. Am i missing something about vendor extensions?

HTML

```
<div class="blobb">
<form id="myForm" runat="server">
  <input id="info" type="text" placeholder="Info" />
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.blobb{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 15px 25px 0 25px;
  margin: 15px 0px 15px 30px;
  cursor: default;

  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #ccaa99;

  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Need to see a test case - Firefox should draw the corners. What element are you applying the radius styles on?

Comment: I put a class on a DIV. And i get rounded corners otherwise but on in there. I assumed it had to do with the vendorless border-radius but i might be mistaken. I added the code to the question.

Comment: Chrome switched from the `-webkit-` to the unprefixed name in version 5. Firefox switched from `-moz-` to the unprefixed name in version 4. Details here: http://caniuse.com/border-radius

Comment: Works for me in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/LHfn4

Comment: @Sime Vidas - Great page. According to it, even IE has finally come to its senses and border-radius can be use prefix-lessly on all browsers. So, WHY on Earth people keep nagging about using it with vendor prefixes?! Old habit? Or is there some advantage (except satisfying the people who refuse to upgrade their browsers)?

Comment: @BoldClock - It works for me too, now. I can't explain what happened. Maybe it helped that restarted the whole system. Strange, indeed... Thanks anyway.

Comment: @KonradViltersten It all depends on your audience. If you don't have people with old browsers then you don't need prefixes. For platforms that still see a bunch of people with legacy browsers prefixes are an easy way to satisfy their audience.

Comment: Please put that as the answer so i can check it as done. Also, pelase mention the address provided by Sime Vidas, since it might be a good idea to have it on record in case somebody else looks for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome switched from the -webkit- to the unprefixed name in version 5. Firefox switched from -moz- to the unprefixed name in version 4. Details here: caniuse.com/border-radius – Šime Vidas Jul 29 at 13:03